# EDIT_SCHEMA_VIEW_VALUES RIDC Webcenter Content

Tags: java, view, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I am trying to edit some view values using RIDC Api in Webcenter Content 12c but I have not found any example.

In [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e11011/c05_core012.htm#CSSRG2617) link you can see the doc about it. I think that it does not have sense because there is a unique required parameter that it is the view name. I suppose this service needs other parameter with the new values of the view or something similar.
I know I can do it through admin applets in UCM but I need to do it using RIDC from Java.

Answer (score 1):

Use the service EDIT_SCHEMA_VIEW_VALUES. It is in the documentation, but it is hard to get what you need from there. You will need three things:

1. The view name (schViewName=...)
2. An action (editViewValueAction=edit)
3. All fields from the view and their values

If you sniff the traffic while using the admin applet, you'll get a lot of example data.